# codeigniter rules group form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

As the Codeigniter document said that we can create sets of rules inside form_validation.php config file. I think I have followed the instruction but the problem is that it shows empty error message rather than error message that is set inside the config arrays.
My form_validation.php config file

```
$config = array(
    'users/register' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'user_type',
            'label' => 'User Type',
            'rules' => 'required|in_list[2,3]',
            'errors' => array(
                'in_list' => '%s Accept only agents or owners!'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'first_name',
            'label' => 'First Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, number and space are allowed for %s.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'last_name',
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Fields with red asterisk is required!',
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, number and space are allowed for %s.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'sex',
            'label' => 'Gender',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|in_list[male,female]',
            'errors' => array(
                'in_list' => 'Optional, %s field must be male or female.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' =>'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[25]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'min_length' => '%s must be between 6-25 characters long.',
                'max_length' => '%s must be between 6-25 characters long.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'confirm_password',
            'label' => 'Password confirmed',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[password]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'matches' => '%s doesn\'t match with password field.'
            )
        ),              
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'is_unique' => '%s is already taken.',
                'valid_email' => '%s must be valid. For example, johndoe@example.com'
            )
        )
    ),
    'users/update_address' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'house_number',
            'label' => 'House Number',
            'rules' => 'trim|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, space and number are allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'street_number',
            'label' => 'Street Number',
            'rules' => 'trim|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, space and number are allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'city_id',
            'label' => 'City or Province',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'district_id',
            'label' => 'District or Khan',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'commune_id',
            'label' => 'Commune or sangkat',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And here is my users controller

```
class Users extends AL_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(['url','form']);
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->model('ion_auth_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

public function update_address() {
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            redirect(base_url(). 'users/login', 'refresh');
        } else {
            if($this->form_validation->run('update_address') == FALSE) {
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));
            } else {
                $user_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
                if($this->user->edit_user_address($user_id)) {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'msg' => 'Your address has been updated!'));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Unable to update your address. Please refresh your page and try again.'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error message show up

```
{"status":"ERROR","msg":"Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.","err":{"errors":""}}
```

Comment: `try putting var_dump($data)` before `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));` see what are results

Comment: array(1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: see there is no messages to show it's empty

Comment: Yes sure still empty string. I think it's Codeigniter bug?

Comment: you have set this `$this->form_valiation->set_rule($config);`

Comment: this will generate errors because the default is autoload. As the document said the form_validation is associated with class/method name convention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90736/discussion-between-anmol-raghuvanshi-and-daroath).

Comment: `$this->config->load('form_validation');` //you didn't loaded this file in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar to this, but I'm not using class/method name association in the config file. I have done like below:

**form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
    'register' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'user_type',
            'label' => 'User Type',
            'rules' => 'required|in_list[2,3]',
            'errors' => array(
                'in_list' => '%s Accept only agents or owners!'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'first_name',
            'label' => 'First Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, number and space are allowed for %s.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'last_name',
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Fields with red asterisk is required!',
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, number and space are allowed for %s.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'sex',
            'label' => 'Gender',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|in_list[male,female]',
            'errors' => array(
                'in_list' => 'Optional, %s field must be male or female.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' =>'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[25]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'min_length' => '%s must be between 6-25 characters long.',
                'max_length' => '%s must be between 6-25 characters long.'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'confirm_password',
            'label' => 'Password confirmed',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[password]',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'matches' => '%s doesn\'t match with password field.'
            )
        ),              
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email',
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Required field.',
                'is_unique' => '%s is already taken.',
                'valid_email' => '%s must be valid. For example, johndoe@example.com'
            )
        )
    ),
    'update_address' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'house_number',
            'label' => 'House Number',
            'rules' => 'trim|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, space and number are allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'street_number',
            'label' => 'Street Number',
            'rules' => 'trim|alpha_numeric_spaces',
            'errors' => array(
                'alpha_numeric_spaces' => 'Only letters, space and number are allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'city_id',
            'label' => 'City or Province',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'district_id',
            'label' => 'District or Khan',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'commune_id',
            'label' => 'Commune or sangkat',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural',
            'errors' => array(
                'is_natural' => 'Only number is allowed for %s'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**Controller Class**

```
class Users extends AL_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(['url','form']);
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->model('ion_auth_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

public function update_address() {
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            redirect(base_url(). 'users/login', 'refresh');
        } else {
            if($this->form_validation->run('update_address') == FALSE) {
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));
            } else {
                $user_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
                if($this->user->edit_user_address($user_id)) {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'msg' => 'Your address has been updated!'));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Unable to update your address. Please refresh your page and try again.'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In `autoload.php`, I have added `$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');` to load form_validation config.

Hope this will works for you as well. Let me know if you facing any other issues.

Comment: from your experience can we show error message like this {
  "status": "ERROR",
  "msg": "Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.",
  "err": {
    "errors": {"house_number":"Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number},
              {"street_number":"Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number"}
  }
}

Comment: In my application, I have handled it in a different way. I'm storing `validation_errors` in a variable then I have written a method which accepts that variable data and loop through each item and show error message in a modal popup.

Comment: As per your example what data you are getting for line `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));`? Can you please paste it here? BTW `{ "status": "ERROR", "msg": "Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.", "err": { "errors": {"house_number":"Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number}, {"street_number":"Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number"} } } ` is a json document. All end user are not that experience to understand it. You have to show a proper validation message for user.

Comment: If `json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));` line returning correct data as per you expectation, then can you please tell what you need next?

Comment: I want the error of specific field, for example if the house_number field is incorrect then it return {"house_number":"Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number}  a key value-pair something like this

Comment: OK. what `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data));` returning now for you? Is the `validation_errors()` not returning correct data for you?

Comment: echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'err' => $data)); this line of code will show like this {"status":"ERROR","msg":"Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.","err":{"errors":"<p>Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number<\/p>\n<p>Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number<\/p>\n"}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90798/discussion-between-deepak-biswal-and-daroath).

Comment: `print_r($this->form_validation->error_array())` and check what it is returning for you!

Comment: yes, thanks guy. it shows Array
(
    [house_number] => Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number
    [street_number] => Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number
)

Comment: OK. Now you can proceed with your functionality :). Please accept the answer if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

application/config/form_validation.php

you have defined your  form validation rules there

so you have to load

```
$this->config->load('form_validation');
```

and try to access config rules as

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('users/update_address'));
```

see if this help

Comment: doesn't work guy. item('$config['users/update_address']')); variable cannot be in single quote

Comment: @Daroath typo `$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('users/update_address'));` see if this works

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. The Codeigniter documentation doesn't say for clear about the class/method name association. When I'm changing from

```
$this->form_validation->run('update_address') == FALSE
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->run('users/update_address') == FALSE
```

However, the message show like below is hard to figure out for sure which error go for which field. Any better answer will be appreciated.

```
{"status":"ERROR","msg":"Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.","err":{"errors":"<p>Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number<\/p>\n<p>Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number<\/p>\n"}}
```

Comment: this will completely fixed my problems echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'msg' => 'Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.', 'errors' => $this->form_validation->error_array())); thanks @Deepak Biswal for help. give me errors as expected {
  "status": "ERROR",
  "msg": "Your form contains error(s). Please fix it.",
  "errors": {
    "house_number": "Only letters, space and number are allowed for House Number",
    "street_number": "Only letters, space and number are allowed for Street Number"
  }
}